# Encode flv video with no audio with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, flv

I'm making an application that needs to convert videos to webm or mp4, it works great with all videos I've tried, but it fails if I use a flv file with no audio channels.

```
$ ffmpeg -i 0986229665-339108519108-86498841039-6078455325.flv out.webm
ffmpeg version 0.7.3-4:0.7.3-0ubuntu0.11.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the Libav developers
  built on Jan  4 2012 16:08:51 with gcc 4.6.1
  configuration: --extra-version='4:0.7.3-0ubuntu0.11.10.1' --arch=amd64 --prefix=/usr --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avutil      configuration: --extra-version='4:0.7.3ubuntu0.11.10.1' --arch=amd64 --prefix=/usr --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdirac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  avcodec     configuration: --extra-version='4:0.7.3ubuntu0.11.10.1' --arch=amd64 --prefix=/usr --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdirac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil    51.  7. 0 / 51.  7. 0
  libavcodec   53.  6. 0 / 53.  6. 0
  libavformat  53.  3. 0 / 53.  3. 0
  libavdevice  53.  0. 0 / 53.  0. 0
  libavfilter   2.  4. 0 /  2.  4. 0
  libswscale    2.  0. 0 /  2.  0. 0
  libpostproc  52.  0. 0 / 52.  0. 0
[flv @ 0x2184560] Could not find codec parameters (Audio: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, 0 channels)
[flv @ 0x2184560] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from '0986229665-339108519108-86498841039-6078455325.flv':
  Metadata:
    audiocodecid    : -1
    server          : Red5 Server 1.0.0 RC1 $Rev: 4193 $
    duration        : 3
    canSeekToEnd    : true
    videocodecid    : 2
  Duration: 00:00:03.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 640x362, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, 0 channels
Incompatible sample format '(null)' for codec 'libvorbis', auto-selecting format 's16'
[buffer @ 0x21852c0] w:640 h:362 pixfmt:yuv420p
[libvpx @ 0x2184040] v0.9.6
[libvorbis @ 0x2185ee0] oggvorbis_encode_init: init_encoder failed
Output #0, webm, to 'out.webm':
    Stream #0.0: Video: libvpx, yuv420p, 640x362, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libvorbis, 0 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

If I pass the -an option, it works, but I can't do that because then all videos wouldn't have audio.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the question-- do you want the transcoded files to have audio or not? Also, FFmpeg appears to claim that the FLV file in your example has not audio.

Comment: I want the transcoded files to have audio if the original have audio, and don't give an error if the original doesn't have audio. Yes, the FLV in the example doesn't have audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is extremely unusual. If the source file has no audio stream, then FFmpeg is not supposed to attempt to transcode an audio stream.

Where did you obtain this version of FFmpeg from? Did you compile it yourself? The version looks a bit out of date. And this line from the output does not sit well with me:

```
WARNING: library configuration mismatch
```

Also, it's possible that there is something weird about those FLV files (output by Red5, if the metadata is correct). Perhaps there is a NULL audio tag for some reason. Would you be able to make a small sample available for study?

Comment: I was using ffmpeg from the ubuntu repositories, compiling it myself fixed the problem! Thanks for the help :)